# React setState – Asynchronously change element class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am building an accordion in which accordion items will only open if `onCLick` the mapped key assigned to the item matches a state held key.

If matched, the class of `accordion-item-opened` is added to the class list by a ternary operator. This uses the max-height hack to open the item. Clicking a different accordion item changes the state held key and therefore opens the clicked item and closes the previous item.

### The problem:

Logically speaking, this all works. Items open and close. The problem is that they open and close **instantly**. There is a transition applied to the class to smoothly transition between `max-height:0;` and `max-height:17rem` which is not firing.

My assumption as to why this is happening is something to do with the asynchronous nature of setState.

The state looks like this:

```
    this.state = {
      vpWidth: 0, //ignore
      breakpoint: 797, //ignore
      activeIndex: 0,
    }
```

`data` comes from a graphQL query and then mapped to the functional component containing the accordion item `div`, for context, that looks like this:

```
              {data.map((node, index) => {
                return (
                  <>
                    <li {...{ className: "accordion-list-item", index }}>
                      <TestItem {...node} index={index} />
                    </li>
                  </>
                )
              })}
```

The functional component containing the accordion item `div` housing both the ternary operator and the `onClick` looks like one of these two ways I have tried it. The first looks like this:

```
const TestItem = ({ node, index }) => {
      return (
        <div
          className={
            "accordion-item " +
            (index == this.state.activeIndex ? "accordion-item-opened" : "")
          }
          onClick={() => {
            if (index != this.state.activeIndex) {
              this.setState({ activeIndex: index })
            }
          }}
        >
          //the rest of the component
```

This works as far as assigning the class and opening the item. However the transition does not fire.

I've atempted something like the below but this does nothing at all. I assume that, because of setState being async, at the time the ternary operator tests its argument `index` does not equal `test`. However the console log will show as true when the `onClick` is fired.

```
    const TestItem = ({ node, index }) => {
      let test = null
      return (
        <div
          className={
            "accordion-item " + (index == test ? "accordion-item-opened" : "")
          }
          onClick={() => {
            if (index != this.state.activeIndex) {
              this.setState({ activeIndex: index }, () => {
                test = index
                //lets say index == 1
                console.log(test) //1
                console.log(index) //1
                //yet the ternary operator fails.
              })
            }
          }}
        >
```

Perhaps there is some way to directly assign the element class in the setState callback. If so, it's not something I have seen or done before and would be very interested to see.

### SCSS

Stripped down to only the relevant parts.

```
@mixin transition(
  $property: all,
  $duration: 0.25s,
  $ease: cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1)
) {
  -webkit-transition: $property $duration $ease;
  transition: $property $duration $ease;
}
.accordion-item {
  $self: &;
  &-opened {
    #{ $self }-inner {
      max-height: 17rem;
    }
  }
  &-inner {
    @include transition;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
  }
```

Comment: can you post the relevant CSS?

Comment: @DanO sure. Added.

Comment: `this.state` and `this.setState` fundamentally won't work in a function component. Either use a class component or the `useState` hook.